# Is there any delay on workmanager execution when started from background thread vs when started from main thread?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have a oneTimeRequest that run some task now I want to know what is the diffrence when I enque this request in workmanager via main thread and background thread. Is there any delay in starting dowork ?

Comment: Yes, the delay is reliant on what other tasks are infront of it. Look up what a Queue is if you dont understand this, it will answer your question. A queue is like waiting in line at the pot shop

Comment: @Joe: additonaly delay when starting from background or you are talking in general

Comment: If your thread starts in the background somehow prior to the main thread, i.e you have a hook beneath the onStart methods, then this would be faster. You will probably want to make a worker thread off of the main thread, and from there, create your background workers in that thread